# Meaning of $\propto$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If I have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ with density $f(x) \propto ce^{-2|x|},x\in \mathbb{R}$, I can interpret that $\propto \equiv =$? If yes, the joint density should be $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=c^2e^{-2(|x|+|y|)}$, right?

Comment: Nope. $f \propto g$ means $\exists c_1. f = c_1g$. So it has to be $c_1c_2e^{-2(|x|+|y|)}$.

Comment: It depends on how you read the $c$. If it is an arbitrary number then you cannot move from proportionality to equality.  If it is the value which makes this a probability density (in this case $c=1$) then you can, though note that if the densities are different then their $c$s may differ too